# Mobile client, server, data integrity rules, logic duplication

Tags: android, ios, design-patterns, data-integrity, duplication

**I have** mobile application and a server. Users can register via my mobile app. Users enter their e-mail and desired password in order to register. There are rules that applied to the password, for example, password length, characters allowed, etc. Each password entered is checked according to these set of rules before the user is allowed to proceed with registration.

**My assumption** is that the server is totally responsible for data integrity and compliance to the all logic rules. So server must check all the data anyway.
So, user enters the password, password (along with e-mail) is sent to the server, server checks both and in case of any problem returns the error to the client with a message that describes the error.
App just shows this message: "Password must contain at least one number". User notified.

BUT

It could take some time before server's reply reaches client. User could be unhappy to get the message after 5 seconds of waiting.
So, I think it would be nice to check the password before the request and notify the user rapidly about rules violated.
The simplest solution is just duplicate the rules within client code.

Here the moment when **the problem** raises. Logic duplication is something I really want to avoid. So I'm thinking about some kind of API end-point that returns all the rules (for ex.: password rules) in json or XML format. These rules could be configured on the server only and whenever changed - will be definitely applied by all clients.
It seems for me the solution that both allows me to make "fast password compliance checks" on the client and avoid logic duplication. But isn't it look too complicated?

**My question** is: what is the best (recommended) way to implement these rules in order to avoid logic duplication and make password check process not dependent on network connection quality?

Answer (score 0):

Your checks for password INTEGRITY (length, chars, etc) should always be handled client-side. Checks for password VALIDITY should ALWAYS be handled by the server. You should not experience much latency, even on 3g with a simple auth query to a server-side script unless the code on the server-side is substandard.

"duplicating rules" is vague but either way I don't see the issue with what you are trying to do. Create a class specifically to handle validation client-side or if the app is HTML5 then use a library like parsleyjs.

Comment: Probably you have not understand the problem. Say I have iOS and Android client apps. Say password policy changed (min length increased). This change have to be applied across the whole system: both on client apps and the server. Imagine that Android guys have forgotten (for some reason) to change integrity check code. In this case Android app password integrity check logic will differ from the server side one.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean, but simple checks like 'string length' should not throttle the response to the app even if they have lots of apps open on the phone. To avoid this adopt uniform standards for password solvency from the get go, like min 8-16 chars etc so you wont have to break conventions or make constant changes to a deployed+compiled app. I understand your concerns but this should not be a trivial issue